# redirect specific page category if not logged in

Tags: wordpress, function, redirect

I'm sure this was working but now it's not. I added categories to pages with:

```
 function add_categories_to_pages() {
 register_taxonomy_for_object_type( 'category', 'page' );
 }
 add_action( 'init', 'add_categories_to_pages' );
```

then tagged a range of pages with a 'client' category and added to functions:

```
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'client_redirect_to_login' );
function client_redirect_to_login() {
$category_slug = 'client';
global $pages;
if ( ! is_user_logged_in() && in_category( $category_slug, $pages ) ) {
wp_redirect( site_url( '/login' ) ); 
exit();
}
}
```

the intention, simply enough, is that not logged in users trying to directly access any of the 'client' pages is redirected to my custom /login page. being returned directly to the page they were trying to access would be a bonus but this, THIS, used to work. there's a dozen pages and growing, so restricting by category is easier than by page ID array - but i can't see what i'm doing wrong.

all advice greatly appreciated!

Comment: From [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Global_Variables) `$pages` will return: `The content of the pages of the current post. Each page elements contains part of the content separated by the <!--nextpage--> tag.` And you need either post/page ID or object

Comment: thanks @dingo_d, got it; removed global and $pages and it works, with the category slug too. thanks!

Comment: Cool :) I'll add this as an answer then :)

Comment: yes please, and thanks again. in_category works, though, with ($category_slug). what's the *correct* way to do it?

Comment: I updated the answer, you can check it and see if it works :)

Answer (score 0):

From [global variables pages in codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Global_Variables) `$pages` will return:

> The content of the pages of the current post. Each page elements contains part of the content separated by the `<!--nextpage-->` tag.

And you need either post/page ID or object when using `in_category()` function as a second argument, as noted [here](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/in_category/).

You can try to get the category of the visited page by setting:

```
$current_cat = get_the_category();
```

And then check

```
in_category( $category_slug, $current_cat );
```

inside the conditional.